# how to make a navigation menu item slide to another menu

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I have an app with a navigation drawer and a NavigationView, I want it to slide to another menu when a specific navigation drawer item (filterButton in my code) is clicked.

I tried to put my navigation view inside a frame layout and using "beginTransaction" so it would open another fragment. I also tried it the other way around, the frame layout inside the navigation view. It didn't work.

From onNavigationItemSelected in my MainActivity.kt

```
// temp dummy fragment
        val blankFragment = BlankFragment.newInstance()
        if (item.itemId == R.id.filterButton) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentMenuParent, blankFragment).commit()
        }
```

this is my activity_main

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentMenuParent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="@string/layers_item">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/nav_layers"
                android:checkableBehavior="all">

            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/filterButton"
        android:title="filter" />
</menu>
```

and this is how I want it to look like-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEGsq.gif

Comment: Hi, please add your beginTransaction code as well.

Comment: just did :) @SnehaSarkar

Answer (score 0):

*Things you need to take care from your side -*

**1.** When you are implementing navigation item click make sure you didn't add the drawer close code. Drawer should be opened when you click on any item.

**2.** `OnClick` of menu, you need to `add` next fragment rather than `replacing` it. Because if you click back from sub menu you need to come back to your actual menu.

```
/**
     * Adds the Fragment into layout container
     *
     * @param container                   Resource id of the layout in which Fragment will be added
     * @param currentFragment             Current loaded Fragment to be hide
     * @param nextFragment                New Fragment to be loaded into fragmentContainerResourceId
     * @param commitAllowingStateLoss     true if commitAllowingStateLoss is needed
     */
    fun addFragment(container: Int, currentFragment: Fragment, nextFragment: Fragment, commitAllowingStateLoss: Boolean) {

        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.apply {
            this.add(container, nextFragment, nextFragment.javaClass.simpleName)
            this.addToBackStack(nextFragment.javaClass.simpleName)

            val parentFragment = currentFragment.parentFragment
            this.hide(parentFragment ?: currentFragment)

            if (!commitAllowingStateLoss) this.commit()
            else this.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }
```

**3.** `OnBackPress` of your activity you need to check whether your `drawer` is open or not. 
If yes, check which fragment is currently visible. If, `SubMenuFragment`, then do `popBackstack` else if `MenuFragment`, then `close Drawer`.

**NOTE:** You need to do all this steps by keeping the frame layout inside your navigation view.

Comment: thanks! though i'm not sure i understand, there is no currentFragment where I want to add this fragment, so I tried it without the hide part and it didn't work.

Comment: @amitmor Inside frame layout, you need to replace MenuFragment. Then you need to add SubMenuFragment. So while adding SubMenuFragment, your current fragment will be MenuFragment. You can't achieve it via normal navigation item thing. Create your custom fragment for first menu as well.

Comment: So you think I should have a menuFragment instead of the normal menu layout file?

Comment: yes I think that's how it can be achievable. @amitmor

Answer (score -1):

try this code

step :1

```
 NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.account_navigation_view);

if (mNavigationView != null) {
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

}

stpe: 2

```
 onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();
```

}